# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.IDataProtector'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a custom service which in that I'm using Microsoft's `IDataProtector`.
I have registered my service in startup with `AddScoped` but i have a problem with using `IDataProtector`.

error message:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.IDataProtector' while attempting to activate 'Service'.

here is  my code :

```
public class Service: IInjectable
{
    private readonly IDataProtector _protector;
     
    public Service(IDataProtector protector)
    {
      _protector = protector.CreateProtector("key");
    }

    other code ...
}
```

The way I have registered my service:

```
    public static void RegisterScoped<T>(
        this IServiceCollection services, params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> types = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes())
            .Where(c => c.IsClass && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(c));

        foreach (var item in types)
            services.AddScoped(item);
    }
```

StartUp :

```
 services.RegisterScoped<IInjectable>(typeof(IInjectable).Assembly);
```

Comment: `services.AddDataProtection();` ?

Comment: @viveknuna I have several services , cause of that i didn't add them one by one

Comment: @GuruStron didn't work :(

Comment: @GuruStron yes you are right, I misunderstood the question

Comment: @user13409315 Still not resolving? can you please add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally , i found the problem :

i had to use IDataProtectionProvider instead of IDataProtector  in my service constructor

Comment: Not the first time I'm using DPAPI in my app, not the first time I even made this mistake either.